# How to use OffscreenCanvas in Jest Typescript test?

Tags: typescript, ts-jest

I have a Typescript class with a instance variable reference to `OffscreenCanvas`:

**foo.ts**

```js
export class Foo {
   private _canvas = new OffscreenCanvas(256, 256);
   ...
}
```

I'm trying to test the code in `foo.ts` using Jest with the following test:

```js
import {describe, expect, test} from '@jest/globals';
import { Foo } from '../src/foo';

describe('foo module', function() {
    test('should test foo', () => {
        new Foo();
    });
});
```

This test is ran with `ts-jest` and executed using `npx jest`. When running the test, I see the following error output:

```
ReferenceError: OffscreenCanvas is not defined

      304 |
      305 | export class Foo {
    > 306 |     private _canvas = new OffscreenCanvas(256, 256);
          |                           ^
      307 | }
      308 |
      309 |
```

I suspect this is because browser features like `OffscreenCanvas` are not available since the test is executed using Node. My question is: is something like this possible without trying to mock out `OffscreenCanvas`? Any way to integrate node-canvas?

A couple of things tried so far: 1) Since it's complaining about it not being defined, I tried installing the types from `@types/offscreencanvas` and then adding them to `types` property in `tsconfig.json`:

```
...
"types": ["offscreencanvas"],
...
```

No luck with this. I also tried adding `jest-canvas-mock` to see if that would help, to no avail. Any help or pointer in the right direction would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: I have the same problem just now, i wanted to write a globalmock

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this is not a perfect solutions, but its a working one. You can just add a Mock in the beforeEach of your Testsuite.

```
beforeEach(async () => {
    window.OffscreenCanvas = jest.fn().mockImplementation((width: number, height: number) => {
        return {
            height,
            width,
            oncontextlost: jest.fn(),
            oncontextrestored: jest.fn(),
            getContext: jest.fn(() => undefined),
            convertToBlob: jest.fn(),
            transferToImageBitmap: jest.fn(),
            addEventListener: jest.fn(),
            removeEventListener: jest.fn(),
            dispatchEvent: jest.fn()
        } as unknown as OffscreenCanvas;
    });
});
```

Naturally it will return `undefined` on the following `canvas.getContext("2d")` call, which in my case leads to an expected error which i catch.

Comment: Yeah, I ended up going a similar route as well. Appreciate the feedback.